# how to make a div (flexbox) stay in a fixed position while scrolling (did a table with divs)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a table made with divs, using flexbox to obtain a nice table formatting of my divs.

Now I got a structure like this:

```
<div class="tableWrapper">
<div class="tableHeader">   
    <div class="tableHeaderRow">
        <div class="tableHeaderCells"></div>
        <div class="tableHeaderCells"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tableBody">
    <div class="tableBodyRow">
        <div class="tableBodyCells"></div>
        <div class="tableBodyCells"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tableBodyRow">
        <div class="tableBodyCells"></div>
        <div class="tableBodyCells"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tableBodyRow">
        <div class="tableBodyCells"></div>
        <div class="tableBodyCells"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

so now what I would like to achieve is to have the "tableHeader" always stay in the same position, so when the "tableBody" content is big (it could have 50rows) and doesn't fit in the browser screen, when the user scrolls down, the header follows so it's always visible.

I tried with `position:fixed` but then it messes up the "tableBody" content.

Here the current css:

```
    .tableWrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    position: relative;
}

.tableHeader {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.tableHeaderRow {
    display: flex;
    height: 35px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    align-items: center;
}

.tableHeaderCells {
    display: flex;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.tableBodyCells {
    display: flex;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.tableBody {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.tableBodyRow {
    display: flex;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

here a fiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/06L52wm1/5/)

so the final result I would like to obtain is, with a body with over 50rows, I want the user to be able to scroll down while leaving the header always on screen, and a plus would be that the "scroll size" (don't know how to call it) is equal to the rows height, meaning that when the user scrolls once, it will go down a fixed amount and exactly put a body row under the header, to avoid that when the user scrolls you get the header, and under it a cut in half body row, hope you understood what I mean!

Answer (score 1):

Please check this you can use `position: sticky;` instead of `position: sticky;` please check fidle, hope it will help you
https://jsfiddle.net/06L52wm1/36/

Comment: already saw it and answered you in your first post! need additional help with the scrolling issue as explained

Answer (score 0):

.tableWrapper`{`position:relative;`}
.tableHeader`{`position:absolute;`width:100%:`}

Comment: ? sorry didn't understand, putting potision:absolute on the tableHeader doesnt change anything, it just messes up the body overlapping the header

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your issue was with position:fixed but it doesn't seem like it changes the body content.

```
.tableHeader {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    z-index:999;
}
.tableBody {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/06L52wm1/34/)

There is still an issue with the width of the header though but I think you can set it by removing the the body margin from the tableHeader's width with calc()
.

Comment: your solution is the same as the user below this answer, so gonna ask you the same

ok this is what I came up with using position: fixed, this can work, but the most important thing is to somehow modify the scrolling, meaning is it possible to make it that when the user scrolls once, it will scroll exactly how much is needed to align the next set of body rows to the header? hope you understand what I mean, now when you scroll, it just scrolls, so after 1 scroll, the current top body row is cut, I want it that the scroll puts the row exactly under the header